# Recover Marginal Distribution subject to a Constraint

Tags: probability, proof-verification, normal-distribution, problem-solving

I want to identify the marginal of a normal distribution subject to a restriction.

Take two normally distributed random variables $x,y$. Their pdfs are denoted by$\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$. The moments of the marginal of $y$ and the conditional of $y|x $ are known and given by $y \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma^{2}_y)$ and $y|x \sim N(\mu_{y|x}, \sigma^{2}_{y|x}) $ respectively. How can one calculate the moments of the distribution of $x \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma^{2}_{x})$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\phi(y) = \int  \phi(y|x) \phi(x)  dx 
\end{equation}
is satisfied?

Instead of trying to solve the problem brute force, I exploited the following known relationships:

\begin{align}
E(Y) &= E_X( E(Y|X) ) \\
Var(Y) &= E_X ( Var(Y|X) ) + Var_X ( E (Y|X)) 
\end{align}

Employing these two relationships render solving the problem above much easier. Can I indeed use these two relationships?

Comment: Plug and chug; it looks messy.

Comment: @probablyme Thank you for your reply! I already applied brute force but was discouraged somewhere on the way ;) I thought there must be a more clever way to tackle the issue. In particular, I hoped for a relationship among conditional moments. Is there no relationship among, e.g. $Var(y)$ and $Var(y|x)$ involving (the desired) $Var(x)$?

Comment: It was not clear what you are looking for. Originally you ask for the moments of $X$. But you also claim that you have the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$. Then you say it was easier to solve $E[Y]$ and $\text{Var}[Y]$. If you are looking for $E[Y]$ and $\text{Var}[Y]$ and you know the distribution of $Y|X$, then what you have is fine.

Comment: @probablyme Thank you for your reply! Well, I'm still looking for the distribution of x. As $x$ is normally distributed, the first two moments suffice. But as the moments of $y$ and $y|x$ are known, the two equations at the end should enable me to recover the moments of $x$, no? Do you agree with the reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint you mention isn't really a constraint.

$\int \phi(y|x) \phi(x) dx = \int \phi(x,y) dx = \phi(y)$

where $\phi(x,y)$ is the joint distribution of X and Y, which in this case is bivariate normal. So this doesn't impose any constraints on the moments of X other than the standard ones for a normal distribution.